# Send text using Android Studio and MQTT broker

Tags: android, mqtt

I'm using Kotlin. You can also answer in Java.
Currently, I want to send a message from Android Studio to the MQTT broker.
However, if the activity is not connected, the message is delivered, but when the activity is connected, an error occurs that cannot connect to the server.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            connect()
        }
    }

    private fun connect() {
        val topic = "/example"
        val content = "Send Message"
        val qos = 2
        val broker = "tcp://localhost:1883"
        val persistence = MemoryPersistence()

        try {
            val Client = MqttClient(broker, MqttClient.generateClientId(), persistence)
            val con = MqttConnectOptions()
            con.isCleanSession = true
            println("Connecting to broker: $broker")
            Client.connect(con)
            println("Connected")
            println("Send Message: $content")
            val message = MqttMessage(content.toByteArray())
            message.qos = qos
            Client.publish(topic, message)
            Client.disconnect()
            exitProcess(0)

            Toast.makeText(this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()

        } catch (ex: MqttException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()
        }
    }
}
```

The above code was created by referring to several examples.

```
W/System.err: Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:74)
        ... 2 more
```

The above information is in error.

Here, if you execute the "fun connect()" function alone, a message arrives.
Can you tell me where I was wrong when I tried to send a message when I click the button on the function to be executed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANDROID-MQTT :Unable to connect to server (32103)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514541/android-mqtt-unable-to-connect-to-server-32103)

Comment: `localhost` is the phone (or emulator) not the address of the host running the broker

Answer (score 1):

When the code runs on the phone (or in the emulator) the hostname `localhost` will resolve to the phone (or emulator) not the machine the MQTT broker is running on (I assume your development machine).

If running in the emulator you can use the IP address `10.0.2.2` but this should only be used for local testing.

You need to use the IP address of your development machine on the network to test from a phone attached to the same network as the development machine.

For further testing/deployment you will most likely need a broker that is publicly accessible from the internet.

Comment: Are you saying that you should write down the ip address that the broker is using, not the localhost?

Comment: I'm saying that unless the broker is running on the phone then `localhost` will never be the right hostname